# Evento onkeyup (Javascript/Jquery) acionado repetidamente faz navegador travar

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener, keyup

Na minha página tenho uma lista com alguns botões representando dados que são apresentados em outra seção da página quando o botão "Submeter" é clicado, acionando a função submeter. Eu adicionei essa função que recebe um termo da lista para submeter os dados sem precisar clicar no botão, apenas apertando "Enter" no teclado. Além do "Enter", a função contava com as teclas de direção "Esquerda" e "Direita" para selecionar e apresentar o anterior ou o próximo item da lista. Acontece que quando o evento é acionado repetidas vezes (mais ou menos como a função seria utilizada pelo usuário) o navegador começa a travar e não se recupera. Só fechando e reabrindo para funcionar novamente. Segue trecho do código:

```
function cursor(c){
    $(document).on('keyup', function(e){
        e = e.which;
        if (e == 13) {
            num = parseInt(c, 10);
            obj = listaGC[num];
            submeter(obj);
        }
    })
}
```

Se alguém puder me explicar porque isso acontece, ou melhor, como contornar, eu agradeço.

Comment: O 'keyup' só deve ser chamado uma vez.